# Excel VBA. Does this macro produce random permutations?

Tags: excel, vba

I'm relying on this macro to produce random sequences at the moment, and I just wanted to check that the sequences I'm getting are indeed random (well, the best a computer can do at random obviously).

```
Sub Random()
For x = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
   r = Int(Rnd(1) * (Selection.Rows.Count) + 1)
   For z = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count
       y = Selection.Cells(x, z).Formula
       Selection.Cells(x, z).Formula = Selection.Cells(r, z).Formula
       Selection.Cells(r, z).Formula = y
   Next z
Next x
End Sub
```

Sorry for the terribly pedestrian question but I need peace of mind on this.

Thanks very much

Comment: A side query - What is in your Selection? I can't see how you are doing this? A variant array would be quicker than your range writing if speed is an issue

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this line right after the `For` line

```
Randomize Timer
```

That will ensure that you never get the same random numbers again since it uses the timer as a seed for the randomness of the produced numbers.

Your code should be

```
Sub Random()
For x = 1 To Selection.Rows.Count
   Randomize Timer
   r = Int(Rnd(1) * (Selection.Rows.Count) + 1)
   For z = 1 To Selection.Columns.Count

       y = Selection.Cells(x, z).Formula
       Selection.Cells(x, z).Formula = Selection.Cells(r, z).Formula
       Selection.Cells(r, z).Formula = y
   Next z
Next x
End Sub
```

Comment: Agree with  using `Randomize` to change the seed. Although from xl-2010 Help `Randomize uses the return value from the Timer function as the new seed value.`

Comment: Correct. Randomize uses a number to initialize the Rnd function random-number generator, giving it a new seed value. If you omit number, the value returned by the system timer is used as the new seed value.

If Randomize is not used, the Rnd function (with no arguments) uses the same number as a seed the first time it is called, and thereafter uses the last generated number as a seed value.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/randomize-statement